# mongodb update add each map structure's value

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

There is a map data `{"a": 2, "c": 4: "d": 0}`,
and a document in MongoDB:

```
{
    ...
    Score: {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 0,
    }
}
```

The updated document:

```
{
    ...
    Score: {
        "a": 3,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 4,
        "d": 0,
    }
}
```

Is what I wanted, now this works well:

```
bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"Score.a": 2,....}},
```

How can I use a map without knowing its keys to update the document in MongoDB? Map to struct? Or use MongoDB `.map` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the map value, you *know* its keys, you can loop over them, and build the "dynamic" update document manually.

This is how it could look like:

```
m := map[string]int{
    "a": 2,
    "c": 4,
    "d": 0,
}

incDoc := bson.M{}
for k, v := range m {
    incDoc["Score."+k] = v
}
updateDoc := bson.M{"$inc": incDoc}
```

Printing the result with

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", updateDoc)
```

Output would be:

```
bson.M{"$inc":bson.M{"Score.d":0, "Score.a":2, "Score.c":4}}
```